# How to integrate Apple Watch into a static library project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I am new in Apple Watch development and want to integrate apple watch functionality into an application project who has a static library into.

I would like to develop all the apple watch's classes and the storyboard into that static library, but I couldn't do that because it seems that i couldn't load the storyboard unless I define that in the 'global app' project. I don't Know if it's possible or it's only allow to define that in the 'app' project, and how can I do that.

Comment: Hi. The static lib cannot contains anything other than compiled code. The storyboard you can add up to a separate bundle. Then from the code need explicitly point to the bundle which contain storyboard.

Comment: Thank you very much, I added the storyboard in a bundle into the static library, but how could call apple watch classes from the 'global' project?,  how could detect the RemoteInterfacePrincipalClass in this subproject? i try to configure in the infoplist 'global' project but i couldn't load the screen.